# How do you go over the [0,1] range for Colors

Tags: tables, color

When I go over the !100 in shading, it gives me an error, however it still works. And simply, my question is: how do I get rid of this annoying error?

```
\documentclass{article}
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    \usepackage{xcolor}
    
    \begin{document}
    
    \centering
    \fboxrule = 5pt
    \setbox0=\hbox{\begin{minipage}[h][2in][t]{3in}
        \color{white}
        \centering 
        hello
    \end{minipage}}
    \fcolorbox{orange!120}{black}{\box0}
    
    \end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! You had not go over 100!

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it's possible because in the `xcolor` [documentation](https://mirrors.mit.edu/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/xcolor/xcolor.pdf), it specifically states on page 13 that the percentage must be in the interval [0,100], so you're always going to get that error unless you somehow rewrite the package. However, the `x11names` option has colors DarkOrange1, 2, and 3, so maybe try using those. To use it, in your preamble you'd put `\usepackage[x11names]{xcolor}`, and then you could put `\fcolorbox{DarkOrange2}{black}{\box0}`. If you don't like those options, the `x11names` option also has the colors Brown1, 2, and 3, I think `\Brown1` looks pretty similar to `orange!120`. You can also always check the xcolor documentation that I linked above to browse different colors, this is pages 39-41. Hope this helps.

Comment: Just as an addition, this problem I have is something I'm trying to implement to the row color of tables, meaning because I already have \usepackage[table]{xcolor}, LaTeX doesn't allow me to use another package that is xcolor. Does there happen to be a feature where I can use them both? If then, this would definitely work.

Comment: Yes, you can put `\usepackage[table,x11names]{xcolor}`

Comment: Curiously, if you write `\colorlet{orangething}{orange!130} ...
\color{orangething}{something}` it doesn't give errors. If you write `\color{orange!130}{130}` it gives `! Package color Error: Argument "-0.3" not in range [0,1].` The output result, however, it's the same.

Comment: I opened an issue https://github.com/latex3/xcolor/issues/22 to the package maintainers.

Answer (score 1):

The best thing to avoid the error is not to use such an invalid value. These mix values should be integers between 0 and 100.

The error is actually not from `xcolor` but from the backend code of the `color` package:

```
! Package color Error: ....
```

`xcolor` itself tries to avoid such out-of-range errors but this case is not catched.

As you found out there are ways to avoid the error, and we will perhaps add something to `xcolor` to suppress it all together, but keep in mind that getting no error doesn't mean that you get the "correct", wanted color. How the package handles values that are out of range is an implementation detail that you can't really control.

For example, currently your work-around gives the rgb values `1 0.4 0`. (and so a bit less green as the original orange which has the values `1 0.5 0`). If I correct the error and truncate the `120` to `100` at the begin, `orange!120`  will be identical to `orange!100`.  Which means that your document colors will change after an xcolor update.

Answer (score 0):

I found out that you can work around this by defining orange!130 yourself and using it.

```
\colorlet{orangething}{orange!130}
```

Which doesn't create an error for

```
rowcolor{orangething}
```

Problem Solved

Comment: It doesn't give errors but it doesn't work. Compare `\colorlet{orangething}{orange!130}` with `\colorlet{orangething}{orange!150}` or `\colorlet{orangething}{orange!300}`. See also my comment under the other answer.

Comment: If what you are referring to is the indistinguishability between orange!150 and orange!300,try mixing the two colors together with a different color, the one I used was black!39: \colorlet{orangething}{orange!150!black!39!} and 
\colorlet{orangeno}{orange!300!black!39!}. Despite combining them with the same color, it gives different results, meaning orange !300 and orange!150 are different. I should apologize for the readability of this comment, as I don't know basic syntax within stackexchange.

Comment: See Ulrike's answer